# Get an anonymous download link using C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I need to generate anonymous links to certain files, using C#, in order to give **view access** to them (or force user to download them once clicked on the link)

**I only have access to the file relative path**.

My credentials are stored in a config file and are used when calling the function `Crud.GetSharepoint()`

Here is my code snippet :

```
// Crud.GetSharepoint returns a ClientContext object
using (var spCtx = Crud.GetSharepoint())
                {
                    foreach (string attachment in attachments)
                    {
                        if (spCtx.HasPendingRequest)
                            spCtx.ExecuteQuery();
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = spCtx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(attachment);
                        spCtx.Load(file);
                        spCtx.ExecuteQuery();
                        // Custom made function that someone advised to use because he coded it
                        // Would prefer using Sharepoint functions directly
                        links.Add(Crud.GetAnonymousLink(spCtx, file, 2, true));
                    }
                }
```

This code works fine but I need to make some few improvements related on these points :

- Url generation works great and my url ends with `?Download=1`. Yet
  since the last update, not all files extensions get downloaded
  directly (everything that is viewable by your internet browser gets
  downloaded, otherwise you are redirected to a webpage where you can
  see the file)
- When I use the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File` object, load time
  get extended as files get bigger (is this normal behavior ?). I only need meta-infomation about the file, not it's content

Any suggestions to improve this ?

Answer (score 1):

1. The "Web.CreateAnonymousLink" is only available for SharePoint Online.
2. You can try to fetch only the meta-data of the file, using CAML:

> ```
> CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
>
> camlQuery.ViewXml = "View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ServerUrl'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>/sites/contoso/Shared Documents/5a8b6e84409589b59936f0fcadf7f99e.jpg</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Size' /><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' /><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='ServerUrl' /></ViewFields></View>";
>
> ListItemCollection listCol = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
> ```

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.createanonymouslink.aspx#

Comment: 1. We are using sharepoint online
2. I will try your CAML query but i was wondering what is docList ?

Comment: docList is List object

Comment: @rak007 Great. That means you can use "Web.CreateAnonymousLink". For e.g.                                     
`Web.CreateAnonymousLink(clientContext, "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/shared%20documents/1.png", false). `                                                                                                          You can get the base URL with spCtx.Url. You no longer have to access the object of the file, or the properties.